# Salesforce 1 view page css

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am trying to develop a opportunity view page on salesforce 1. This is my custom page. Is there any css library which provide look and feel for that.

trying to achieve following:- [image: screen]

screen shot

Answer (score 0):

Look at the post [salesforce1 look & feel in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/salesforce1-look-feel-in-Visualforce).

This should help

> All CSS applied in Salesforce1 is under the parent selector .oneStyle.
>   So wrap your html code in a container div and apply .oneStyle class to
>   it. This will make sure that all Salesforce1 css effects will we
>   mobile compatible. And copy CSS style for each element from SFOne and
>   copy it to you visualforce page. Thats not the best way but little
>   understanding of css may not require best method (if exists).
>
> For more information here basic details has been provided to give
>   Salesforce1 look and feel to pages:
>   http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/salesforce1-look-and-feel-customise-visualforce-pages-for-salesforce1/

Answer (score 0):

There is cool plugin developed by Josh for Salesforce1 style in VF at - https://github.com/joshbirk/onestarter and working demo is available at - http://sfdc-styleguide.herokuapp.com/