# How to add a scrolldown function in Visualforce for a Salesforce1 Lightning app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, scrolling

I cannot find a way to add a scrolling bar to my Salesforce1 app, changing the height (in pixels) in the Lightning Force editor is not giving any result. Page is truncated at some point on my phone even if it is not in the Lightning preview.
PS: the following snippet doesn't work in my case..

```
<head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,minimum-  scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/> 
</head>
```

Find my page below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="Account_Controller_2" action="{!displayAccount}" docType="html-5.0" standardStylesheets="true" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
<script>
    function ExitButton() 
    {
        sforce.one.navigateToURL("/home/home.jsp");
    }
 </script>
<style type="text/css">
    .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
    .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;padding:1px 2px;border-style:solid;word-break:normal;}
    .tg .tg-io3b{font-size:12px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6090F0;}
    .tg .tg-nuj7{font-size:12px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000;}
    .forcePanelOverlay .panel{display:block; overflow:y;}
</style>
 <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=800px, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/> 
 </head>
 <apex:form id="theForm">
     <section id="status" style="text-align: center; display: none;"></section>
     <div id="Account Section">
         <div style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px;"><b>Account<apex:inlineEditSupport /></b></div>
         <table class="tg">
             <tr>
                 <td class="tg-io3b">
                     <b><apex:outputLabel value="Name"/></b>
                 </td>
                 <td class="tg-nuj7">
                     <apex:outputField value="{!account.Name}"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td class="tg-io3b">
                     <b><apex:outputLabel value="Current Status"/></b>
                 </td>
                 <td class="tg-nuj7">
                     <apex:inputField style="width:250px;height:50px" id="Status" required="false" value="{!account.Last_Status__c}"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td class="tg-io3b">
                     <b><apex:outputLabel value="Additional Info"/></b>
                 </td>
                 <td class="tg-nuj7">
                     <apex:outputField value="{!account.Additional_Information__c}"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td class="tg-io3b">
                     <b><apex:outputLabel value="Last contact"/></b>
                 </td>
                 <td class="tg-nuj7">
                     <apex:outputField value="{!account.Last_Update__c}"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td class="tg-io3b">
                     <b><apex:outputLabel value="Problem?"/></b>
                 </td>
                 <td class="tg-nuj7">
                     <apex:outputField value="{!account.Ongoing_Problem__c}"/>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </div>
     <div id="Buttons Section" style="display:block;overflow:auto;">
         <apex:pageBlock > 
             <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top" style="position:fixed;width:300px;left:0;right:0;margin-left:10px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;">
                 <apex:commandButton style="background:#6090F0;height:20px;width:60px;color:#000000;" value="OK" action="{!OK}" id="OKButton"/>
                 <apex:commandButton style="background:#6090F0;height:20px;width:60px;color:#000000;" value="NOT OK" action="{!notOK}" id="NotOKButton"/>
                 <input type="button" value="EXIT" onclick="ExitButton()" id="btnExit" style="background:#6090F0;height:20px;width:60px;color:#000000;"/>
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
         </apex:pageBlock>
     </div>
     <div id="Contacts Section" style="display:block;overflow:auto;">
         <div style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:14px"><b>Contacts</b></div>
         <style type="text/css">
             .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;display:block;overflow:visible}
             .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px;padding:3px 2px;border-style:none;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
             .tg .tg-io3b{font-size:11px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6090F0;}
             .tg .tg-nuj7{font-size:11px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000;}
         </style>
         <table class="tg">
             <thead>
                 <tr class="tg-io3b">
                     <th>Name</th>
                     <th>Phone</th>
                     <th>E-Mail</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <apex:repeat value="{!contacts}" var="cont_acc">
                     <tr class="tg-nuj7">
                         <td>{!cont_acc.Name}</td>
                         <td><apex:outputLink value="tel:{!SUBSTITUTE(cont_acc.Phone,' ', '')}">{!cont_acc.Phone}</apex:outputLink></td>
                         <td><apex:outputLink value="mailto:{!cont_acc.Email}">{!cont_acc.Email}</apex:outputLink></td>
                     </tr>
                 </apex:repeat>
             </tbody>
         </table>
     </div>
</apex:form>
<div style="display:block;height:88px;overflow:visible"></div>
```

Screenshot below could probably clarify the problem (Grey part at the bottom is the end of the page, but it shouldn't. More contacts are linked to this account..):
[image]

Any tips?
Thanks in advance for your help on this, Francesco

Answer (score 1):

Use a dummy div below your lightning tab/page.

```
<div style="display:block;height:88px;overflow:visible">
</div>
```

Reason why bottom is cut sometimes?

Salesforce1 uses `overflow:hidden` css style everywhere to support touch-drag perfectly. Sometimes it prevents scroll on custom lightning pages because scroll is off by `overflow` class.

You may hack and override `overflow` and `display` css but it may not longer work as Salesforce can change those css selector if needed.

CSS Workaround, you can put CSS as:

```
             <style type="text/css">
                .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
                .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;padding:1px 2px;border-style:solid;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
                .tg .tg-io3b{font-size:12px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#6090F0;}
                .tg .tg-nuj7{font-size:12px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000;}

                .forcePanelOverlay .panel { overflow-y:scroll !important; }

            </style>
```

Also, as I can see your are trying to make page of Salesforce1. Here is a link which can help you: http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/salesforce1-look-and-feel-customise-visualforce-pages-for-salesforce1/ from [salesforce1 look & feel in Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25541/salesforce1-look-feel-in-visualforce)

Comment: Hello Ashwani, thanks for your answer but this is not exactly what I need. Your trick adds visible space to the block I want, but it doesn't increment the total length of the page, which is what I need to do.
In other words, the total height of the page is now = to the device heigth. I would like to have it > device height, scrolling down (only when necessary of course). Is this feasible? 
If you need to check the .vfp file content just ask..
Cheers, Francesco

Comment: Another workaround you can use is css: `.forcePanelOverlay .panel { overflow-y:scroll !important }` @FrancescoAlfeo

Comment: I edited my question adding page code and a screenshot, couldn't use your workaround (probably it would work, but I'm not a css master)..

Comment: @FrancescoAlfeo Updated my answer so you can put CSS

Comment: Also can you set `standardStyleSheets=false` @FrancescoAlfeo

Comment: Done, no changes.. Actually now page is a little smaller (two contacts less)

Comment: Again, no changes. But thanks for the link: http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/02/16/salesforce1-look-and-feel-customise-visualforce-pages-for-salesforce1/
It will be surely very useful!

Comment: Hi I'm using jquery mobile tabs and having issues with similar issue. I tried .forcePanelOverlay .panel { overflow-y:scroll !important } and it's not adding scrollbar though. Any ideas?